# Script Python on ArcGIS works but do nothing

Tags: arcpy, fields-attributes, loop

I am trying to automate a loop for the Alter Field tool. As the code snippet that comes with the help fits my problem, I used it by changing the workspace path. I also tried passing the path with GetParameterAsText. The script work fine and ends without bugs, but it run very fast (0.04 s). In fact, when I check the names in the fields I see that it does nothing.

Does anybody know what is the problem?

I'm using win 10 and ArcGIS Desktop 10.4.4. The last code snippet is below.

```py
#Import geoprocessing
import arcpy
import os
#Set workspace
arcpy.env.workspace=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses() #get a list of feature classes
for fc in fcList:  #loop through feature classes
    fieldList = arcpy.ListFields(fc)  #get a list of fields for each feature class
    for field in fieldList: #loop through each field
        if field.name.lower() == 'Elevation':  #look for the name Elevation
            arcpy.AlterField_management(fc, field.name, 'EL', 'Elev')
```

It neither works even if I use the same code of the example 2 of the tool, but with the exact name 'Elevation':

```py
 #Import geoprocessing
import arcpy

#Set workspace
arcpy.env.workspace = r'E:\DICEA_WORK\SURVEY LAB\MUSA\PROCESSING\INPUT\COSMO\Elaborazione_CSK_continuoASICOSMO_ptc9\Geodatabase.gdb'

#Loop through feature classes looking for a field named 'Elevation'
fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses() #get a list of feature classes
for fc in fcList:  #loop through feature classes
    fieldList = arcpy.ListFields(fc)  #get a list of fields for each feature class
    for field in fieldList: #loop through each field
        if field.name == 'Elevation':  #look for the name elev
            arcpy.AlterField_management(fc, field.name, 'ELEVATION', 'Elevation in Metres')
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. In the future, please take the time to add diagnostic print statements and evaluate your flow-of-control ***before*** posting a question. At a minimum, it will improve your question, and it might even lead you to understand why certain control points are never visited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scripts reads the lower case field name, and compares it to a name having a capital letter... so the condition is never satisfied!

```
if field.name.lower() == 'elevation'
```

Comment: It neigher worked with: field.name == 'Elevation' neither field.name.lower() == 'levation'

Comment: It neither works even if I use the same code of the example 2 of the tool, but with the exact name 'Elevation':

Comment: @user3265206 Is it really called 'Elevation'? Double check that it is not the alias

Comment: @user3265206 you may also want to close/reopen Arcmap. I found that sometimes the fields are cached and not properly refreshed after some modifications

Comment: Now it works! I reopened Arcmap, and did other tries changing the new field name by 'ELEV' or 'COTA', and it changed names perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
if field.name.lower() == 'Elevation':
```

Is impossible. `.lower()` will always return a string of all lower case letters. The string you have given to compare it with has `E` in it.

Try using:

```
if field.name.lower() == 'elevation':
```

Instead.